# Convert FLOAT(12,2) to DECIMAL(12,2)

Tags: mysql

I need to convert database column from `FLOAT(12,2)` to `DECIMAL(12,2)`. There are not many rows in the table (approx. 100K) so migration time should not be a problem and I can run the statement directly without any temporary columns, etc. like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `{name}` CHANGE `{column}` `{column}` DECIMAL(12, 2) NOT NULL
```

My only question is whether I can expect any value loss from this transformation. I suppose not because precision is the same. Can you confirm my assumption?

Comment: I would not expect any loss of information in going from float to decimal with the same precision.  But, since you were using float, the values already in that column might not be exact values (because floating point is not exact).

Comment: There won't be any loss in precision, however I suspect the table size (in bytes) will grow. I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performed basic test

```
SELECT * FROM float_test

0.30
0.12
0.70
5561064448.00
2734151168.00
7367510528.00
5589978112.00
591043776.00
9939725312.00
1450539136.00
2416124160.00
123580832.00
814644608.00
410369856.00
2416124160.00
2416124.25
241612.23

ALTER TABLE float_test CHANGE test_value test_value DECIMAL(12, 2) NOT NULL

17 row(s) affected, 4 warning(s):
 1265 Data truncated for column 'test_value' at row 1
 1265 Data truncated for column 'test_value' at row 2
 1265 Data truncated for column 'test_value' at row 3
 1265 Data truncated for column 'test_value' at row 17
 Records: 17  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 4    0.125 sec

SELECT * FROM float_test

0.30
0.12
0.70
5561064448.00
2734151168.00
7367510528.00
5589978112.00
591043776.00
9939725312.00
1450539136.00
2416124160.00
123580832.00
814644608.00
410369856.00
2416124160.00
2416124.25
241612.23
```

Despite warnings all the data is the same. And it did take a while
So run the query )